# Having troubles with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am taking user inputs and storing them in an XML file. I am reading an XML file and storing all the data under tags in an array in javascript. So that if the user inputs the same email address twice, I can let them know that this email already exists in the XML file. So that it doesn't store the same email in the XML file twice as the user can't sign up. But for some reason, the function isn't working. I really need some help to figure this out.
my XML file (storedata.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<data><fname>Sammy</fname><lname>Kim</lname><email2>kim2000@gmail.com</email2><pass2>123</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Jimmy</fname><lname>Jabs</lname><email2>jim@gmail.com</email2><pass2>abc</pass2></data>
</document>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml->load("storedata.xml");
    
    $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("document")->item(0);
    
    $dataTag= $xml->createElement("data");
    
    $name1= $xml->createElement("fname",$_REQUEST['fname']);
    $name2= $xml->createElement("lname",$_REQUEST['lname']);
    $emailadd= $xml->createElement("email2",$_REQUEST['email2']);
    $pwd= $xml->createElement("pass2",$_REQUEST['pass2']);
    
    $dataTag->appendChild($name1);
    $dataTag->appendChild($name2);
    $dataTag->appendChild($emailadd);
    $dataTag->appendChild($pwd);
    
    $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);
    
    $xml->save("storedata.xml");    
}
?>
```

my form input:

```
<input type="email" name="email1" placeholder="Email Adress" required="required" class="input-txt" style="width:40%;" id="email1">
<input type="email" name="email2" placeholder="Confirm Email Adress" required="required" class="input-txt" style="width:40%;"id="email2">
```

my Javascript code:

```
<script>

var first_email = document.getElementById("email1")
  , second_email = document.getElementById("email2")
  , password = document.getElementById("password")
  , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");
 
//making an array of the email addresses from the XML file 
const email_array = new Array();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "storedata.xml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("data");
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var names = user.getElementsByTagName("email2");
    for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        email_array.push(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}

//looping through the array to find out if same email exists, if it does, increase count by 1
var i; var count =0;
for (i=0; i<email_array.length; i++) {
    if (first_email == email_array[i]) {
        count++;
    }   
}

//checking if the email already exists in the XML file
function checkuser() {
    if (count>=1) {
        email1.setCustomValidity("This email address already exists! Please use another one.");
    }
    else {
        email1.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
email1.onchange = checkuser;

function validateMail() {
if(first_email.value != second_email.value) {
    email2.setCustomValidity("Emails Don't Match");
  } else {
    email2.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

email2.onkeyup = validateMail;
```

Comment: Personally, I think this is too similar to [what you asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321957/re-enter-email-validator-not-working-on-javascript) but didn't do or say anything about it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "isn't working" is not a good problem description. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: I am really confused cause I tried the array in another separate code and it's working okay. I don't know if it's not working because of how I declared my variables or not, and if the count is actually increasing (it's a global scope, so it should increase) It just stores same emails in the xml file twice, the checkuser function isn't doing anything

Comment: for now, what I can see is that, the array works fine, but the count isn't increasing

Comment: I changed the counter because o the closure, it still doesn't work ``` var increase_count = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  var i;
  return function () {
   for (i=0; i<email_array.length; i++) {
     if (document.getElementById('email1').value == email_array[i]) {
  counter++;
     } 
      } 
  return counter;
  }
}
)(); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Create an `existingEmails` arrays after retrieving the emails.
- Then in the `checkEmailExists` function you will check if the email is in the array.

```
<script>

var first_email = document.getElementById("email1")
  , second_email = document.getElementById("email2")
  , password = document.getElementById("password")
  , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");
 
//making an array of the email addresses from the XML file
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "storedata.xml", false);
request.send();

var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("data");
const existingEmails = [];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const emailTag = users[i].getElementsByTagName("email2");
    const email = emailTag[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    existingEmails.push(email);
}

//checking if the email already exists
function checkEmailExists() {
    if (existingEmails.includes(first_email.value)) {
        first_email.setCustomValidity("This email address already exists! Please use another one.");
    } else {
        first_email.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}

email1.onchange = checkEmailExists;

function validateMail() {
    if(first_email.value != second_email.value) {
        email2.setCustomValidity("Emails Don't Match");
    } else {
        email2.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}

email2.onkeyup = validateMail;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said, It doesn't work. It still adds duplicate mails to the xml file.

Comment: Oh now it works, I just used the ids instead of the variable names while calling javascript event. Thank you so so much!